# How can I print the loss value obtained from model.add_loss() function in Tensorflow 2 (with Keras API)?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a classification model in Keras API of Tensorflow 2. The model has two losses in the example below, categorical cross entropy and KL-divergence. Categorical cross-entropy is being added while initializing the model and hence it can be printed while training. KL-divergence is being added separately using model.add_loss(). However, it does not display during training. Is there a way to print it while training? The sample code is shown below. Since it is on simulated data, loss value might come to be nan.

```
import tensorflow as tf
keras = tf.keras
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

def ohc(y):
  y = np.random.randint(4, size=100)
  b = np.zeros((y.size, y.max() + 1))
  b[np.arange(y.size), y] = 1

  return b

xtrain = np.random.rand(100,50)
y = np.random.randint(4, size=100)
y_one_hot = ohc(y)

def my_kld(y_true, y_pred):

  y_pred2 = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x + 0.00001)(y_pred)
  LR = y_true/y_pred2
  logLR = K.log(LR)
  kld = y_true*logLR
  loss = K.mean(kld)
  loss = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * 0.2)(loss)
  return loss

x_t = keras.layers.Input((50,))
y_t = keras.layers.Input((4,))

x1 = keras.layers.Dense(100, activation = 'relu')(x_t)
x2 = keras.layers.Dense(4, activation = 'softmax')(x1)

model = keras.models.Model([x_t,y_t], x2)
model.add_loss(my_kld(y_t, x2))

optim = keras.optimizers.Nadam(0.00006) 

model.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy'], optimizer=optim, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=[xtrain,y_one_hot], y = y_one_hot, epochs = 100)
```

The code that I have tried has been included in the question in an implementable way. Hwever, there does not seem to be any way to print the loss from model.add_loss().